# Maven and net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-maven-plugin

Tags: maven

I am working today with personnal (and old) maven project. When I launched :

```
mvn clean package
```

I received an error with description `null` so I thought it was because I used a beta version of `flexmojos-maven-plugin` (but 2 months ago, it was working). I saw there is a new (and stable) version of plugin which groupId isn't `org.sonatype.flexmojos` but `net.flexmojos.oss`. I refactored my project and launched it but all dependencies were unrecognized because this plugin searches for flex framework version `4.6.0.23201` but available version on repository is `4.6.b.23201`...Strange

[see](https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/com/adobe/flex/framework/framework/)

So I refactored my POM to use `4.5.1.21328` version but I have these warnings :

> [WARNING] The POM for com.adobe.flex:compiler:pom:4.6.0.23201 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for com.adobe.flex.compiler:mxmlc:jar:4.6.0.23201 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for com.adobe.flex.compiler:digest:jar:4.6.0.23201 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for com.adobe.flex.compiler:optimizer:jar:4.6.0.23201 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for com.adobe.flex.compiler:asdoc:jar:4.6.0.23201 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for com.adobe.flex.compiler:swcdepends:jar:4.6.0.23201 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING]
>   [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.sim:sim-flex-bases:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.graniteds:granite-essentials-swc:swc must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'internal'. @ line 30, column 11
>   [WARNING]
>   [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
>   [WARNING]
>   [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
>   [WARNING]
>   [INFO]

As you can see, this plugin is looking for `4.6.0.21328` version again, I don't know why...here is my plugin code :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>net.flexmojos.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-swc-bases</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-swc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeClasses>
                            <scan>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com.sim.**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <!-- <excludes> -->
                                <!-- <exclude>com.sim.tide.events.**/*</exclude> -->
                                <!-- </excludes> -->
                            </scan>
                        </includeClasses>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.1.21328</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.1.21328</version>
                    <type>pom</type>

                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.1.21328</version>  <!-- this artifact version must match the flex SDK version used in this project -->
                    <classifier>10.2</classifier>  <!-- the classifier specifies the target flash player major version -->
                    <type>swc</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <configuration>
                <targetPlayer>10.0.0</targetPlayer>
                <compilerWarnings>
                    <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>
                </compilerWarnings>
                <keepAs3Metadatas>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Bindable</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Managed</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>ChangeEvent</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>NonCommittingChangeEvent</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Transient</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Id</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Version</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Lazy</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Name</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>In</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Out</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Inject</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Produces</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>PostConstruct</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Destroy</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>Observer</keepAs3Metadata>
                    <keepAs3Metadata>ManagedEvent</keepAs3Metadata>
                </keepAs3Metadatas>
                <baseOutputDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</baseOutputDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

So how can I see default dependencies used by a plugin and how can I modify them ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread after facing this issue today.

Using the dependency inside the net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-maven-plugin plugin as below helped me:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.b.23201</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As for the question on how you can see dependencies on the plugin, I believe you should refer to the plugin's pom.xml, but I'm unaware of any way to modify them.